# To read all characters from a string entered in text box without duplicates and count of each character

Tags: c#, string

I want to read all characters from a string entered in a text box without repetitions with the count of each character and then store these values to two grid columns using C# ,Asp.Net

eg:`My name is Joe`

```
Characters  Occurances
M               2
y               1
n               1
a               1
e               2
i               1
s               1
j               1
o               1
Total           11
```

and then store these to the grid view columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ operator GroupBy:

```
string str = ":My name is Joe";

var result = str.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).
                 GroupBy(c => char.ToLower(c)).
                 Select(gr => new { Character = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count()}).
                 ToList();
```

That'll give you a list of objects with fields `Character` and `Count`.

EDIT: I added a `Where` clause to filter out non-letter characters. Also added case-insensitivity

Now you have to use the `result` list as a binding source for your grid. My understanding of ASP.NET binding process is a little rusty. It is possible that you'll need to create objects of some class with `Character` and `Count` properties instead of anonymous objects (you can't bind to fields)

Comment: You may have to convert the string char array before using the GroupBy operator ?

Comment: @AB Kolan: you don't need to, you can enumerate over characters of a string object

Comment: @AB Kolan: no problems, I found out about it not so long ago myself. I think it's pretty neat though

Comment: @Dyppl Strange why LINQPad complained about it :/

Comment: @Dyppl LINQPad does not show GroupBy in the AutoComplete as well http://i.imgur.com/TI0Zo.png

Comment: @AB Kolan: that's odd. I wasn't aware of that because I use the free version

Comment: How do we do this without Linq using for loop

Comment: @Violet: I posted an answer with non-linq solutions (it uses foreach loops, but if you really need for loop, it's easy)

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = "My name is Joe";

var result = from c in input.ToCharArray()
             where !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)
             group c by Char.ToLower(c)
             into g
             select new Tuple<string, int>(g.Key.ToString(),g.Count());

int total = result.Select(o => o.Item2).Aggregate((i, j) => i + j);

List<Tuple<string, int>> tuples = result.ToList();

tuples.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Total", total));
```

And you can databind the `tuples` list to the DataGrid :)

Comment: What's up with storing count in string type? It requires additional casting and I don't see any benefits, DataGrid should be smart enough to handle int values

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the LINQ solutions, here's how it can be done using foreach-loops:

```
string str = ":My name is Joe";

var letterDictionary = new Dictionary<char,int>();

foreach (char c in str) {
    // Filtering non-letter characters
    if (!char.IsLetter(c))
        continue;

    // We use lowercase letter as a comparison key
    // so "M" and "m" are considered the same characters
    char key = char.ToLower(c);

    // Now we try to get the number of times we met
    // this key already.
    // TryGetValue method will only affect charCount variable
    // if there is already a dictionary entry with this key,
    // otherwise its value will be set to default (zero)
    int charCount;
    letterDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out charCount);

    // Either way, we now have to increment the charCount value
    // for our character and put it into dictionary
    letterDictionary[key] = charCount + 1;  
}

foreach (var kvp in letterDictionary) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

The output of the last cycle will be:

```
m: 2
y: 1
n: 1
a: 1
e: 2
i: 1
s: 1
j: 1
o: 1
```

Now you have to use some technique from other answers to turn the result into the list of value that can be bound to the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried simple console application..hope this will help you..
you can view this on [Solving Algorithms with C#](http://solving-algorithms.blogspot.com/p/count-each-character-in-string.html)

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]