# To find the occurance of each words in a string and their count in C# using Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

```
string s="hello hi hello how are you you hello";
hello 3
hi    1
how   1 
are   1
you   2
total 8
```

Comment: good progress; from letters to words :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151376/to-read-all-characters-from-a-string-entered-in-text-box-without-duplicates-and-c

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that this is homework, so I'll give you hints:

- `string.Split` (or `Regex.Split` for more complicated scenarios) can be used to split the string into words
- `Enumerable.GroupBy` can create groups easily
- `Count()` can find the size of a group
- `Sum()` can find the sum of the counts

If that doesn't help, please show what you've done already, where you've got stuck etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "hello hi hello how are you you hello";
var x = (from string word in s.Split(' ')
            group word by word
                into g
                select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(g.Key, g.Count()))
        .ToDictionary(kvp1 => kvp1.Key, kvp2 => kvp2.Value);
```

Comment: What is the point in creating `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: no point, just habit. An anonimous class also may be used here.